# USB with Kali Linux 2024.1 (not live) installed not visible in boot menu

Tags: linux, boot, usb, grub, kali-linux

Specifications:

- Laptop: Lenovo Legion Pro 5i (Gen 8)
- CPU: i9 (13th Gen)
- GPU: Nvidia Geforce RTX 4060
- USB B is a SanDisk Ultra Luxe (128GB)

For context:

- Secure boot is off.
- USB ports are working properly.

I have 2 USBs. USB A (Kali Linux 2024.1 installer) and USB B (to be installed with the Kali Linux system). After installation was completed, USB A and B were visible in the boot menu and I was able to
boot into USB B (Kali Linux system). After booting in, I installed GRUB for USB B again as this was my 3rd time trying to fix this problem and I was under the impression that GRUB was not properly installed. After shutting down my laptop and rebooting it, USB B was no longer visible in the boot menu.

Looking for suggestions as to why I am facing this problem and how to fix this.

Background information:

- I am not using a live image of Kali Linux. I am using an installer to install Kali Linux in another USB.
- I have done this before using the same USBs with an older laptop which is no longer functional.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.